# Which data structure should be used, that can be appended in customized way?

Tags: r

I have to load data from files related to multiple experiments, and latter process them for generating a plot. Each experiment generated multiple files. Files related to experiment 1 will have their name "Experiment1" and then postfixed by data type it contains i.e. "Experiment1-per0", "Experiment1-per50", "Experiment1-per100".

These postfixes are fixed for all experiments. So to load the files, I want to give only the experiment names, and latter append the postfixes in R-script. Consequently, for each experiment name "ExperimentX"  I would give, I will load three separate data files by appending the postfixes (i.e "ExperimentX-per0", "ExperimentX-per50", "ExperimentX-per100")

**I am unable to figure out, in which datastructure I should store the initial experiment names and then the postfixed names.**

Sample file (Experiment1-per50):

```
# the last column also shows the type of data i.e postfix of file

Obj TGiven  TUsed   TOGiven TOServed    per50

16570   8   7   12  6   per50

18430   8   8   12  9   per50

16890   8   7   12  9   per50
```

Currently, I put every file name, manually, which takes lot of time.

Comment: Much better question. Make sure to give feedback to the people that answer your questions (esp if their answers don't address your question) and vote them up and/or select the correct "answer" as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each experiment will have the same set of suffixes, you can store your list of experiment names and suffix names separately. Then, using a nested loop, you can combine the experiment name and suffix name using the `paste` function to get the filename.

You code might look something like this:

```
experiments = c("Experiment1","Experiment2","Experiment3")
suffixes = c("per0","per50","per100")

for (experiment in experiments) {
  for (suffix in suffixes) {
    filename <- paste(experiment, suffix, sep="-")
    df <- read.table(filename)
    df$experiment <- experiment
    # Do something with the dataframe here
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want a vector of all the filenames from given `experiments` and `suffixes` lists, this would combine them:

```
as.vector(sapply(experiments, paste, suffixes, sep="-"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## If all the columns are the different

If the columns are different between the experiments, I would wrap the experiments in lists as follows:

```
library(plyr);
experiments <- c("Experiment1","Experiment2","Experiment3");
suffixes <- c("per0","per50","per100");

# if you want to go ahead and get the data
data <- llply( experiments, function(experiment) {
    llply( suffixes, function(suffix) {
        fn <- str_c(experiment,'_',suffix,'.csv'); # make filename
        # later, try to read fn, now just return
        return(fn);
    })
})
```

You can then iterate through `data` for further processing. `llply` is part of the `plyr` package. It iterates over a list (the first `l` in `llply`) and returns a list (the second `l`).

## If all the columns are the same

```
library(plyr);
experiments <- c("Experiment1","Experiment2","Experiment3");
suffixes <- c("per0","per50","per100");

data <- ldply( experiments, function(experiment) {
    ldply( suffixes, function(suffix) {
        data.frame(
           experiment = experiment,
           suffix= suffix,
           fn = str_c(exper.name,'_',suffix,'.csv'))
    })
})
```

This will read all the data as a single `data.frame`, which you can then parse as needed (for example, using `plyr` and/or `subset`).

Comment: Though I understand your purpose (i.e if columns in file are different), I really couldn't get the code. It seems quite complex to me..:(

Comment: Actually, the main difference between @Wilduck's answer is that it uses functional programming rather than for-loops, which are generally frowned upon in R. It can be confusing, but sometime, you might want to take the time to learn. Cheers.